# run jar using classpath option

Tags: java, maven, jar

I have a project with two main methods in two different classes I want to run the jar file of this project using cp option from the cmd and give which method to run its main. example `java -cp myjar-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar  com.xyz.DataLoader` the project itself is maven project and here it's pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.xyz</groupId>
    <artifactId>myjar</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                <version>5.2.15.Final</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                <version>5.1.6</version>
            </dependency>


        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

when I try the command `java -cp myjar-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar  com.xyz.DataLoader` I get the error  `Could not find or load main class com.xyz.DataLoader`
can anyone help with that?

**UPDATE**

the main class:

```
package com.xyz;

import java.io.*;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

public class DataLoader {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /*if(args[0] == null ||args[0].trim().isEmpty()){
            return;
        }*/
        try {
            parseFile("C:\\Users\\MOEL3\\Downloads\\abc\\access.log");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void parseFile(String fileName) throws IOException, ParseException {

        BufferedReader br =getBufferedReaderAndOpenFile(fileName);

        String strLine;
        List<LogElement> logElementList=new ArrayList<>();
        extractLinesAndAddToLogElementList(br, logElementList);

        //Close the input stream
        br.close();
    }

    private static void extractLinesAndAddToLogElementList(BufferedReader br, List<LogElement> logElementList) throws IOException, ParseException {
        String strLine;//Read File Line By Line
        while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
            // Print the content on the console
            logElementList.add(convertLineToLogElement(strLine));
        }
    }

    private static BufferedReader getBufferedReaderAndOpenFile(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException {
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
    }

    private static LogElement convertLineToLogElement(String strLine) throws ParseException {
        String[] data = strLine.split("\\|");
        LogElement element = new LogElement();
        element.setIp(data[1]);
        element.setRequest(data[2]);
        element.setStatus(data[3]);
        element.setUserAgent(data[4]);
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
        Date date = formatter.parse(data[0]);
        element.setRequestDate(date);
        return element;
    }

}
```

Comment: What directory are you in when you run that? By default maven will build the jar in the target directory. If you're in the project root, the class path would be target/myjar-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

Comment: target directory where the jar file is created @Devon_C_Miller

Comment: Does your class `com.xyz.DataLoader` uses any classes from dependencies? You have to add mysql and hibernate into classpath also

Comment: @Ivan no not really I use mysql and hibernate to insert some values in the database but I didn't implement that part yet

Comment: @MuhammadRamahy even usage in `import` or annotation is enough to get that error.

Comment: @Ivan I have added my main class to get a look, I don't see imports that refers to mysql or hibernate

Comment: @MuhammadRamahy You are running `mvn package`, right? Just running `mvn compile` will compile, but will not assemble the jar file.

Comment: I use clean install command which creates the jar

Comment: @MuhammadRamahy have you tried running with full path to that jar?

Comment: @Ivan, it works with full path!